# Implementing a minimal LSTMCell in Keras using RNN and Layer classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement a simple LSTMCell without the "fancy kwargs" defaultly implemented in the tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell class, following a schematic model like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxYtg.png). It doesn't really have a direct purpose, I would just like to practice implementing a more complex RNNCell than the one described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN) in the Examples section. My code is the following:

```
from keras import Input
from keras.layers import Layer, RNN
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

class CustomLSTMCell(Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.state_size = units
        super(CustomLSTMCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.forget_w = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size, self.state_size + input_shape[-1]),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='forget_w')
        self.forget_b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size,),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='forget_b')

        self.input_w1 = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size, self.state_size + input_shape[-1]),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='input_w1')
        self.input_b1 = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size,),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='input_b1')
        self.input_w2 = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size, self.state_size + input_shape[-1]),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='input_w2')
        self.input_b2 = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size,),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='input_b2')

        self.output_w = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size, self.state_size + input_shape[-1]),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='output_w')
        self.output_b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.state_size,),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    name='output_b')

        self.built = True

    def merge_with_state(self, inputs):
        self.stateH = K.concatenate([self.stateH, inputs], axis=-1)

    def forget_gate(self):
        forget = K.dot(self.forget_w, self.stateH) + self.forget_b
        forget = K.sigmoid(forget)
        self.stateC = self.stateC * forget

    def input_gate(self):
        candidate = K.dot(self.input_w1, self.stateH) + self.input_b1
        candidate = K.tanh(candidate)

        amount = K.dot(self.input_w2, self.stateH) + self.input_b2
        amount = K.tanh(amount)

        self.stateC = self.stateC + amount * candidate

    def output_gate(self):
        self.stateH = K.dot(self.output_w, self.stateH) + self.output_b
        self.stateH = K.sigmoid(self.stateH)

        self.stateH = self.stateH * K.tanh(self.stateC)

    def call(self, inputs, states):

        self.stateH = states[0]
        self.stateC = states[1]

        self.merge_with_state(inputs)
        self.forget_gate()
        self.input_gate()
        self.output_gate()

        return self.stateH, [self.stateH, self.stateC]

# Testing
inp = Input(shape=(None, 3))
lstm = RNN(CustomLSTMCell(10))(inp)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=lstm)
inp_value = [[[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]]]
pred = model.predict(inp_value)
print(pred)
```

However, when I tried to test it an exception was raised with the following message:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

in the `call` function at the line where I set the value for `self.stateC`. Here, I thought that initially the `states`argument of the `call` function is a tensor and not a list of tensors, so this is why I get an error. So I added a `self.already_called = False` line to the classes `__init__` and the following segment to the `call` function:

```
 if not self.already_called:
        self.stateH = K.ones(self.state_size)
        self.stateC = K.ones(self.state_size)
        self.already_called = True
    else:
        self.stateH = states[0]
        self.stateC = states[1]
```

hoping that it will eliminate the problem. This resulted in another error at the `merge_with_state` function:

```
 ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'rnn_1/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [10], [?,3], [].
```

which I genuinely do not get, since the RNN layer should only "show" the CustomLSTMCell tensors with shape (3) and not (None, 3), since axis 0 is the axis it should iterate along. At this point I was convinced that I am doing something really wrong and should ask the community for help. Basically my question is: what is wrong with my code and if "almost everything", then how should I implement an LSTMCell from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that I managed to fix the problem. It turns out that it is always useful to read the documentation, in this case the [docs for the RNN class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L196-L962). First, the `already_called` attribute is unnecessary, because the problem lies in the first line of the `__init__` function: the `state_size` attribute should be a list of integers and not only one integer, like this: `self.state_size = [units, units]` (since we need two states for an LSTM of size `units` and not one). When I corrected it I got a different error: the tensors are not compatible in dimension in the `forget_gate` for addition. This happened because the RNN sees the whole batch at once and not each element in the batch separately (thus the `None` shape at axis 0). The correction for it is to add an extra dimension **to each tensor** of size 1 at axis 0 like this:

```
 self.forget_w = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size, self.state_size + input_shape[-1]),
                                initializer='uniform',
                                name='forget_w')
```

and instead of dot products I had to use the `K.batch_dot` function. So the whole, working code is the following:

```
 from keras import Input
 from keras.layers import Layer, RNN
 from keras.models import Model
 import keras.backend as K

 class CustomLSTMCell(Layer):

     def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
         self.state_size = [units, units]
         super(CustomLSTMCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

     def build(self, input_shape):

         self.forget_w = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0], self.state_size[0] + input_shape[-1]),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='forget_w')
         self.forget_b = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0]),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='forget_b')

         self.input_w1 = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0], self.state_size[0] + input_shape[-1]),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='input_w1')
         self.input_b1 = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0]),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='input_b1')
         self.input_w2 = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0], self.state_size[0] + input_shape[-1]),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='input_w2')
         self.input_b2 = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0],),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='input_b2')

         self.output_w = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0], self.state_size[0] + input_shape[-1]),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='output_w')
         self.output_b = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.state_size[0],),
                                         initializer='uniform',
                                         name='output_b')

         self.built = True

     def merge_with_state(self, inputs):
         self.stateH = K.concatenate([self.stateH, inputs], axis=-1)

     def forget_gate(self):        
         forget = K.batch_dot(self.forget_w, self.stateH) + self.forget_b
         forget = K.sigmoid(forget)
         self.stateC = self.stateC * forget

     def input_gate(self):
         candidate = K.batch_dot(self.input_w1, self.stateH) + self.input_b1
         candidate = K.tanh(candidate)

         amount = K.batch_dot(self.input_w2, self.stateH) + self.input_b2
         amount = K.sigmoid(amount)

         self.stateC = self.stateC + amount * candidate

     def output_gate(self):
         self.stateH = K.batch_dot(self.output_w, self.stateH) + self.output_b
         self.stateH = K.sigmoid(self.stateH)

         self.stateH = self.stateH * K.tanh(self.stateC)

     def call(self, inputs, states):

         self.stateH = states[0]
         self.stateC = states[1]

         self.merge_with_state(inputs)
         self.forget_gate()
         self.input_gate()
         self.output_gate()

         return self.stateH, [self.stateH, self.stateC]

 inp = Input(shape=(None, 3))
 lstm = RNN(CustomLSTMCell(10))(inp)

 model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=lstm)
 inp_value = [[[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]]]
 pred = model.predict(inp_value)
 print(pred)
```

**Edit:** In the question I made a mistake with respect to the model linked and used a tanh function in the `input_gate` for `amount` instead of a sigmoid. Here I edited it in the code, so it is correct now.